# Error with audio in sr_freecap captcha extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I implemented sr_freecap extension in form. All works fine except the audio output. Audio works in Safari browser but not in Firefox or Chrome. In Chrome i get the following error in the console:

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

[EDIT]

I made a few more attempts and found that only the first call does result in this error. Let me try to explain it more accurate:

- page is called in browser
- clicks on the audio symbol in the captcha results in this error
- reload the captcha (get a new captcha image)
- clicks on the audio symbol results in playing the correct audio captcha without any error

I analyzed the network traffic for the first click (error) and the click after refreshing the captcha (no error). There is only one difference: the result header Content-Length for the first click is 0. So it seems that the audio file  of the first click is simply empty.

In Safari every click results in a valid audio file.

Any idea what is wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: have you inspected the network tab? is the sound file (given in DOM) requested and what answer came from server?

Comment: After two more hours of testing it seems to be an issue of a self sign certificate. After moving the whole Site to a server with a valid certificate the audio captcha runs in Chrome and Firefox too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue of a self sign certificate. After moving the whole Site to a server with a valid certificate the audio captcha runs in Chrome and Firefox too.